# List of commonly used categories in POIs

Tags: data, point-of-interest

I want to add POI management functionality to an existing software project. Though providing a list of categories seems a bit tricky. On one side, I do not want to reinvent the wheel and create my own categories. On the other side, I could not find a definitive "source of truth" for categorizing POIs.

What POI lists do you know of, and what would be your advice for choosing a set of categories?

To give a bit more context: I'm aware that *OSM* has a quite extensive tag list. Besides *OSM*, there are various vendors having custom / proprietary POI lists. There may also be standards that I'm not aware of which define POI categories as well.

My software tries to address a broad range of POI categories, making it easy for existing solutions to adopt my software. Though since there is no such thing as a standard (that I'm aware of) defining POI categories, I wonder if there is something like a common denominator, e.g. a list of "default" tags that is commonly accepted by different vendors or standards, like a "restaurant" or "toilet" tag.

Comment: Is it enough : https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features ? and I think you can trust the source.

Comment: Which country are you mapping POI's in? I'm sure Afghanistan would have a very different opinion than say the UK... Check the national mapping agency as they may have a definitive  dictionary of terms?

Comment: It‘s for a worldwide available application. The OSM list is not enough. That I mentioned and know already.

Comment: Please clean up your tags, I don't see how any of them except for "point-of-interest" are relevant here.

Comment: The question has only the tag `openstreetmap` so we can't guess, IMHO, that you have already checked the POI list and found it not enought detailled. I think you can add more context to your question to tell where did you search. An other point, I think it's more an open data stack exchange question than GIS one.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I've removed some tags, though added a data tag to address the question to a broader audience. OSM is detailed, but not the only reference. I'll update the question in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are any off-the-shelf solutions to do what you want (perhaps by interogating the [taginfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/) api), but it is an active research topic.

Several researchers have proposed ontologies (or methods for building ontologies) of osm POIs. The general idea is to define a reference vocabulary that allows to link the different tags naming the same type of object, which could act as a default tag list.

I think this article are a good starting point : [SONET: A Semantic Ontological Network Graph for Managing
Points of Interest Data Hetereogeneity](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1606916)